# translating SQL to DQL

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

i'm struggling in translating this to dql

```
SELECT SUM(qtestock)
     , (SELECT nom FROM categorie c WHERE c.idcateg=p.idcateg) nom 
  FROM produit p 
 GROUP 
    BY idcateg
```

Comment: Maybe we can translate a different (and better) query instead. With that in mind, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting on the DQL, I don't know if it will help you but I propose you anyway.
First, I think it would be better to use a join in your query like:

```
SELECT SUM(p.qtestock), c.name FROM product p
INNER JOIN category c on(c.idcateg=p.idcateg) 
GROUP BY idcateg
```

to make it easier. Now we're gonna translate it into DQL:

```
SELECT SUM(p.qtestock), c.name FROM product p
JOIN p.category c 
GROUP BY p.idcateg
```

for more information, please refer to [https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html](http://I'm%20starting%20on%20the%20DQL,%20I%20don't%20know%20if%20it%20will%20help%20you%20but%20I%20propose%20you%20anyway.%20First,%20I%20think%20it%20would%20be%20better%20to%20use%20a%20join%20in%20your%20query%20like:%20%20%20SELECT%20SUM(p.qtestock),%20c.name%20FROM%20product%20p%20INNER%20JOIN%20category%20c%20on(c.idcateg=p.idcateg)%20%20GROUP%20BY%20idcateg%20%20to%20make%20it%20easier.%20Now%20we're%20gonna%20translate%20it%20into%20DQL:%20%20SELECT%20SUM(p.qtestock),%20c.name%20FROM%20product%20p%20JOIN%20p.category%20c%20%20GROUP%20BY%20p.idcateg%20%20for%20more%20information%20please%20refer%20to%20https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html%20%20%20Translated%20with%20www.DeepL.com/Translator%20(free%20version))